# Delete property in referenced JS object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Let's say I want to delete a property in a JS object

```js
const source = {
  nestA: {
    nestB: {
      nestC: 'deleteMe'
    }
  }
}
const clone = {}
clone.nestA = {...source}.nestA
delete clone.nestA.nestB
console.log(source)
```

execute above script
expect: `source` remain untouched
actual: `source` will become `{}`

However, if I just do `delete clone.nestA`, `source` will remain untouched as expected

Question: How come `delete clone.nestA.nestB` affect `source`. But `delete clone.nestA` doesn't?

Comment: `{...source}.nestA` makes no sense, you could (should) just use `source.nestA`.

Comment: The spread syntax assignment does not make a deep copy.

Comment: What is your question? Do you understand why this happens?

Comment: [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)

Comment: In Version 69.0.3497.81 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10, `source` is `{ nestA: {} }`, not `{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How come `delete clone.nestA.nestB` affects `source`, but `delete clone.nestA` doesn't?

`source` and `clone` are distinct objects. A third object is referenced from both the `source.nestA` property and the `clone.nestA` property. (Another object is on the `nestB` property of that).

When you delete a property on `source`, like the `source.nestA` property, you only affect the `source` object.

When you delete a property on the third object, like `source.nestA.nestB` or `clone.nestA.nestB` (which is the same property on the same object), you only affect that third object. It's just that both `source` and `clone` now reference that object which misses a property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use assign method of objects to create deep copy in that way your source can be untouchable.

```
let deepCopy = Object.assign({},source);
// do anything with deepCopy.
```

Update -
It will not create a deep copy of nested object. You can use below method to create a deep copy for nested object.

let deepCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source));

Or

```
function cloneObject(obj) {
var clone = {};
for(var i in obj) {
    if(obj[i] != null &&  typeof(obj[i])=="object")
        clone[i] = cloneObject(obj[i]);
    else
        clone[i] = obj[i];
}
return clone;
}
```

Check

Comment: Not true from what I can see. If you run this, it behaves the same way as the spread example: `const source = {
  nestA: {
    nestB: {
      nestC: 'deleteMe'
    }
  }
};
const clone = Object.assign({}, source);

delete clone.nestA.nestB;
console.log(source);`